# Why we can not say: $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)>\lim_{x \to \infty} g(x)$

Tags: limits, inequality

Given are:

$\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = 0$

$\lim_{x \to \infty} g(x) = 0$  and 
$$\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=k>1$$

> Question: Why we can not say: $$\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)>\lim_{x \to \infty} g(x)$$

Because, for example if  $$\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)=m$$

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)=n$$ and $$\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\frac mn=k>1$$

We can write:

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)>\lim_{x \to \infty} g(x)$$

Why? Or do I think I'm wrong?

Comment: With your hypotheses, $m=n=0$, so $\frac mn$ makes no sense and your $\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ is wrong. Besides, $m = kn$, $k> 1$ does not imply $m > n$, in the case $m=n=0$.

Comment: You already specified that both limits equal $0$. Obviously one cannot be greater than the other, by the trichotomy law of the reals.

Comment: @pseudo why is wrong?? You can try $m=\frac{1}{x^2}$ and $n=\frac{1}{x}$

Comment: $m$ and $n$ are the limits. They are numbers, not functions.

Comment: "Question: why we can not say $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) > \lim_{x \to \infty} g(x)$?" The real question is: why would you be allowed to say that? First you should show the proof or intuition you have about why you think it's true for somebody to be able to point out the mistake.

Comment: @pseudo sorry $f(x)$ and $g(x)$

Comment: @PseudoNeo No, here you seem to be mistaken. $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ (as written in the OP) and $\frac{\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)}{\lim_{x\to\infty}g(x)}$ are two different things. (This does not mean that writing ${\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)} > {\lim_{x\to\infty}g(x)}$ when both limits are zero would make sense; but $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$  can, and often is)

Comment: @Student You *can* in your situation write "$f(x) > g(x)$ on a neighborhood of $\infty$" (which is true based on your assumptions); but you *cannot* write $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)>\lim_{x\to\infty} g(x)$, since then it would be literally equivalent to writing $0>0$. *Once you take the limit, you are only left with numbers...*

Comment: Sorry dear mathematicians, I may have asked you a stupid question.But my english not well..I hope you understand what I mean.

Comment: @Student This is not a stupid question; but did the above and the current answer clarify the situation?

Comment: Yes, of course..dear Clement C. And this inequalty may be true only $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = m$ and $\lim_{x \to \infty} g(x) = n$ and $m$ and $n$ are finity numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you asking why we cannot say

$$0 = \lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) > \lim_{x \to \infty} g(x) = 0$$

namely why we cannot say

$$0>0$$

???

Moreover the fact that we also have

$$\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=k>1$$

is not incompatible with the individual limits being zero. An easy example is

$$f(x) = a/x,\;\; g(x) =b/x,\;\; a>b>0, \;\;\; x \in \mathbb R_{++}$$

Here, we have

$$f(x) > g(x), \;\;\forall x$$

but their respective limits are equal.

Also, each separate function goes to zero... but their ratio is the constant $a/b$.

Think of the ratio as a new function $h(x) = f(x)/g(x)$ with its own properties, that do not necessarily transfer back to the individual elements forming the ratio.

Comment: I understood +1.)

Comment: To the proposer: " $ \;f(x)\to 0$ and $g(x)\to 0$ as $x\to \infty\;$"    is not enough information to say whether $|f(x)/g(x)|$ converges or goes to $\infty$ as $x\to \infty$ even when $g(x)$ is never $0.$ For example $f(x)=1/x$ and $g(x)=(2-\sin x)/x$.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Certainly, but what is the point of your comment? In the OP's post the limit of the ratio is part of the givens.